# Can i run Junit dynamic tests produced by @TestFactory concurrently?

Tags: java, junit5

i am using the [Discovering Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-discovery) feature of Junit and i also have a class that introduces a few `@TestFactory` methods each of which produces a great amount of dynamic tests. My first thought was "It would be great to be able to run these concurrently.", so i added

```
.configurationParameter(
               "junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled", "true"
           )
```

to my `LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder` and i annotated my test class holding the factories with `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)`. So far so good, but i ended up with each `@TestFactory` method being run on a different thread but all the dynamic tests produced by a single `@TestFactory` share the same thread (the thread the `@TestFactory` that produced these tests runs on).

My question is - can i run the dynamic tests produced by a @TestFactory in parallel ? Also tried this

```
@TestFactory
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
```

but the result was the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can execute dynamic tests concurrently.

Here's a modified version of the `dynamicNodeSingleContainer()` test factory from the JUnit 5 User Guide

```
@TestFactory
@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
DynamicNode dynamicNodeSingleContainer() {
    return dynamicContainer("palindromes",
        Stream.of("racecar", "radar", "mom", "dad")
            .map(text -> dynamicTest(text, () -> {
                assertTrue(isPalindrome(text));
                System.err.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            })
    ));
}
```

When I execute it, I see the following output which demonstrates that the 4 dynamic tests executed concurrently in different threads.

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9
```

Comment: It seems the problem is in the content of my factories because i tried your example and it works as expected. Different dynamic test are being picked by different workers. In my case the worker is always the same.

Comment: I found the problem, it was in my implementation. Junit is perfectly capable of running dynamic tests in parallel. Sorry for wasting your time.